# Word for a person who meets all the guests at the entrance

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Could you suggest some options to name a person, someone who meets all the guests at the entrance/at the beginning of some event? Not a Chair.

I know it is not a *bouncer*. Instead, it should be very close to a *host* or a *greeter*. Welcomer? (welcoming person)

Update: For one event only, it is not a permanent job, just a role.

**Greeter**. Thanks to all.

Comment: This would depend upon the nature of the event.  For example, it could be a *bouncer*.

Comment: Thanks, that is not a bouncer, sorry. I've updated the post.

Comment: I went to an event planning website and got one of those annoying pop-ups "Chat with us!  Now!" so I did and asked your question.  He said ***greeter*** (as in @thomj1332's answer) or, maybe, _check-in attendant_.

Comment: https://www.job-applications.com/walmart-greeter/.  “Walmart greeters meet customers at store entrances. Greeters at Walmart may assist customers with cart selection, offer coupons, or simply welcome people to the store.”

Comment: Yes, a greeter, at the place where you enter a venue for an event. It can be a person from the event organizing team or someone who works for the place. Words like attendant are only for those who work for the place. You are looking for something more upscale, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are meeting the guests to welcome them, I'd call them the ***host***.  Or, if they aren't actually the host but just an emissary for the host, I'd called them the ***greeter***.

As mentioned in the comments, if they aren't there to welcome but to vet they'd be called a ***bouncer***.

Comment: Host/greeter are very close - might be welcomer is ok, thanks.

Comment: "host" and "greeter" are totally unrelated, and have no connection to each other.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider ***usher***.

ODO:

> **[usher](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/usher)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A person who shows people to their seats, especially in a theater or at a wedding.
>
> ‘Sarah and Paul have asked me to be one of the two ushers at their
>   wedding.’

American Heritage Dictionary:

> **[usher](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=usher)**
>   *n.*
>
> **2.** **One who greets guests at a wedding** and escorts them to their seats.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not about seats, just meet ans greet people. Neither about tickets.

Comment: Hope you saw the second definition (AHD) which mentions _greeting guests_.

Comment: Yes, I saw, thanks. I also did translation to my first language, and found the connotation is not so relevant to mine, sorry.

Comment: Might be I should search for some examples of use in real texts.

Comment: Try host--although this implies more than greeting.  The people who greet the guests (and are giving the party or event) are the receiving line.

Comment: Yes, the question was about the receiving line, not about the whole hosting. Greeter/welcomer I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In the PTA world, this has been traditionally called the

> Hospitality Chair

or

> Hospitality Committee

It's okay if it's a committee of one.  It is sometimes called the

> Welcoming Committee

Again, it's okay to have only one person in this committee.

Comment: @user236360 - Why don't you post an answer so you can close this out? // I'm glad you settled on a word that works for you.

Comment: Thank you, I've just done it - and now see your comment.

Answer (score -1):

In a formal, commercial setting (such as a restaurant), you could use [Maitre d'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%AEtre_d%27h%C3%B4tel):

> ***[maître d'hôtel](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/maitre_d'hotel)***   (also maître d')
>
> NOUN
>
> 1 The head waiter of a restaurant.
>
> 1.1 The manager of a hotel.

Another option, perhaps, (again, depending on the situation), could be a [Concierge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concierge):

> ***[concierge](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concierge)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1 (especially in France) a resident caretaker of a block of flats or a
>   small hotel.
>
> 2 A hotel employee whose job is to assist guests by booking tours,
>   making theatre and restaurant reservations, etc.

Lastly, (and this is a bit of a stretch,) there is Attendant:

> ***[attendant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attendant)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1 A person employed to provide a service to the public in a particular
>   place.   ‘a cloakroom attendant’
>
> 1.1 An assistant to an important person; a servant or courtier.   ‘a mosaic of the Empress Theodora with her attendants’
>
> 2 A person who is present on a particular occasion.   ‘he had become a
>   regular attendant at chapel’

FWIW, the folks that say "hi" at the door of places like Wal-Mart are called greeters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, great vocabulary. However, it is not so close to the role I'd like to express.

Comment: the matire d'hotel, and the concierge, specifically do Not act as a "greeter".

Comment: Per the linked Wikipedia article, "_The responsibilities of a maître d'hôtel generally include supervising the waiting staff, *welcoming guests* and assigning tables to them, taking reservations and ensuring that guests are satisfied._"  I have dined in many restaurants where the maitre d' met guests and seated them.  Yes, it's the fancier ones (not your Denny's or Applebees) but it is used that way.